# What is the opposite of "upsell"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

The dictionary defines the verb "[upsell](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/upsell)" as such:

> **Main Entry**:       upsell
>
> **Definition**:       to try to
> persuade a customer to buy a more expensive item or to buy a related
> additional product at a discount

It's a fairly common word that gets used a lot in most retail trades.

But the dictionary does not list "[downsell](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/downsell?s=t)" as its opposite. However, it seems to me that the concept of upselling does have a clear opposite concept. i.e. Trying to persuade a customer to buy a cheaper item or fewer items.

Granted, there are fewer situations where this would be used, but I wonder why the word does not exist, and whether there is another word that could be used in its place.

Comment: I would call it "honesty"...

Comment: If the word doesn't exist, it's because there's no need for it.

Comment: *Upsell* has been created to serve a need. There was no need to create a term like *downsell* for something that does not exist, at least not in regular business practice. In cases of exception, you need to say it in as many words: "Trying to persuade a customer to buy a cheaper item or fewer items," else no one would understand. :)

Comment: @BarrieEngland Well said.

Comment: @GuyF-W It need not be honesty; worse, you are also implying thereby that *upselling* is anything but honest!

Comment: @BarrieEngland True, but I can think of words that don't need to exist but do. And this one is such an obvious candidate to be a word, since it would have a clear meaning and its opposite already exists.

Comment: @Urbycoz ~ what you want to call *downsell* is already called a *discount*.

Comment: @RoaringFish Persuading a customer to buy a cheaper item or fewer items is not giving them a discount.

Comment: You state that "there are fewer situations where this would be used", but provide no examples. You state that "you can think of words that don't need to exist but do" and provide no examples.

Comment: @coleopterist Are you disagreeing with either statement, or just moaning? StoneyB gives an excellent example of downselling- an insurance salesman trying to persuade clients from purchasing dubious expensive products to gain loyalty. Words that exist but don't need to- how about *tetrapyloctomy* (The act of splitting a hair four ways), *abacinate* (To blind by putting a hot copper basin near someone's eyes). There really are quite a few http://users.tinyonline.co.uk/gswithenbank/unuwords.htm

Comment: I'm saying that your question is inadequately framed.

Comment: I hope my clarification enables the question to reach your meticulous standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have in fact encountered the word *downsell*, in colloquial and semi-formal contexts: insurance salesmen and financial advisors use it in discussing the need to dissuade clients from purchasing financial products with attractive "features" but dubious benefits.

> He was convinced that the universal policy would guarantee his retirement, and it took a lot of downselling to show him he could accomplish the same thing with a convertible term policy that fit his current budget without the risk.

*Upselling* is deprecated by sophisticated salespeople in the insurance industry, because it's typically a one-off sale, with a greater risk of lapse. *Downselling* leads to longer-sustained relationships, which are ultimately more remunerative for both the agent and, they believe (or at least maintain), the client.

Comment: This ("it took a lot of downselling to show him ...") is not *downselling* -- see OP's explanation in the question.

Comment: sure it is. They're trying to get the customer to buy a cheaper product

Comment: @KateGregory Not in the sense Stoney used it: *a lot of downselling to show him*: should be "a lot of persuasion/ counseling/ educating him to downsell ...".

Comment: @Kris, no, both upsell and downsell are things sales reps do to get customers to buy more/less items or bigger/smaller items. "him" in the quote is the customer who they persuade to buy less. He perhaps downbuys, but he doesn't downsell

Comment: @KateGregory Take your own time to read things over before you post a response :)

Comment: @Kris I'm not really getting your point. Seems the same to me.

Comment: I don't get it either: stoneyB's example is clearly a situation where the person has spent time " to try to persuade a customer to NOT buy a more expensive item."

Comment: @Kris Please take your own time to read things over before you post a patronising comment :)

Comment: @Kris, and others: I think what's giving rise to this  debate is the fact that salespeople often use "sell" (or "upsell" or "downsell") with the **customer** as its direct object, not the product sold.

Comment: That's surprising. StoneyB, who I addressed, got the point right, of all people.

Answer (score 0):

While not an exact opposite, the term *downsizing* is [used](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/downsize?view=uk) to describe a reduction from an earlier, more opulent or generous state

> make (something) smaller: *I downsized the rear wheel to 26 inches*

This is more frequently used when the potential consumer already has a larger, more expensive, more feature-laden version of the item being sold or used.

The term *cut back* is [used](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cut-back) to similar effect.

> to reduce the amount of something, especially money that you spend: *It's time we cut back a little.*
>
> *plans to cut back investment in education*
>
> cut back on: *We're trying to cut back on the amount we spend for food.*

Comment: Note that "downsize" is probably most frequently used to refer to a company laying off employees. It's basically a euphemism for "firing a bunch of people".

Comment: @Jay That is probably the most frequent usage, but it also has very common usage, at least in the US, when referring to moving to a smaller home or buying a smaller car.

Comment: Good point, I'd forgotten those examples. I was thinking of "downsize the wheel", which is used, I'm not disputing that, but is relatively rare.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term *[dissuade from](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dissuade)* meaning:

> to deter by advice or persuasion; persuade not to do something

or the word *[downplay](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/downplay?s=t)* meaning:

> to treat or speak of (something) so as to reduce emphasis on its importance, value, strength, etc.